# Java Could not find main class Error after running by Notepad++

Tags: java, notepad++, command-prompt

I have been running java by `Command Prompt` in Win 7 Ultimate using only filename (Ex. `javac program.java` and java program) before running java by Notepad++ script.

After using Notepad++ script and update Java to version `jdk-8u77-windows-i586` I could only able to run java by Notepad++ only. I get

> Error: Could not find or load main class CopyFile

when I run it in Command prompt. But I can use 'javac' in command line to compile the java program.

Below is my Notepad++ script that runs java program inside of it.

```
NPP_SAVE
cd "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\javac" $(FILE_NAME)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java"  -classpath "$(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)" "$(NAME_PART)"
```

I have checked environment variables and all of them are set. I've given them below.

**CLASSPATH**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_77\bin
```

**JAVA_HOME**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77
```

**Path**

```
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\xampp\ImageMagick-6.9.1-Q16;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27\DLLs;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;D:\Dhay\Tasks by me\Firefox addon job\addon-sdk-1.17\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\lenovo\easyplussdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\
```

Below is the java file.

```
import java.io.*;
class CopyFile
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int i;
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;
        if(args.length != 2)
        {
            System.out.println("Usage: CopyFile from to");;
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
            fout = new FileOutputStream(args[1]);
            do {
                i = fin.read();
                if(i != -1) fout.write(i);
            } while(i != -1);
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e);
        } finally {
            try 
            {
                if(fin != null) fin.close();
            } catch(IOException e2)
            {
                System.out.println("Error Closing Input file");
            }
            try
            {
                if(fout != null) fout.close();
            } catch(IOException e2)
            {
                System.out.println("Error Closing Output File");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even I could able to run it in command line just by

```
java -classpath . CopyFile
```

I am just curious what might be wrong.

Comment: If you try to run from a command line, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I get `Error: Could not find or load main class filename`

Comment: paste your java file

Answer (score 0):

Your current directory is not in your classpath, so java can not find your class,
then you tell java, go current directory to find CopyFile by this:

```
java -classpath . CopyFile
```